# Conditionally create list of lists

Tags: python

I don't know if I'm phrasing this in the best way, but essentially I'd like to create a list of lists based on different conditions.

I read in some XML data using ElementTree and after parsing it, I iterate through the tree and put all of the tags in a list called `tags` and their values in a list called `vals`.

Within my list of tags, there are a few sentence tags that I'd like to make the keys of a dictionary and the corresponding values append to a list and made the values.

My list of tags, their corresponding values, and sentence tags looks like below.

```
tags = ['irrel', 'TAG_ONE', 'TAG_ONE', 'TAG_TWO', 'TAG_ONE', 'TAG_TWO', 'irrel']

vals = ['not_rel', 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 'not_rel']

sent_tags = ['TAG_ONE', 'TAG_TWO']
```

My ideal output is `tags_dict = {'TAG_ONE': [1, 2, 3], 'TAG_TWO': [5, 6]}` which I achieved using the code below.

```
sent_vals = list()

# Make a list of all TAG_ONE values and append list to sentence values list
tag_one = list()
tag_one_locs = [i for i, x in enumerate(tags) if x == 'TAG_ONE']
for t in tag_one_locs:
    tag_one.append(vals[t])
sent_vals.append(tag_one)

# make a list of all TAG_TWO values and append list to sentence values list
tag_two = list()
tag_two_locs = [i for i, x in enumerate(tags) if x == 'TAG_TWO']
for tt in tag_two_locs:
    tag_two.append(vals[tt])
sent_vals.append(tag_two)

tags_dict = dict(zip(sent_tags, sent_vals))
```

However, this is fairly ugly and just copying and pasting code a million times is impractical as my real data has about 70 sentence tags. I'm drawing a blank on how to simplify the code into some sort of list comprehension (or something else).

Comment: start by not calling your variables `tag_one_locs`, `tag_two_locs` but create dictonaries with `TAG_ONE`, etc... as keys. Then you can loop on the tags.

Comment: or just use the same variable and a loop

Comment: `tags` and `vals` are missing

Comment: I think it can be done in one line with comprehensions, but provide minimal data like wjandrea commented. putting on hold until it's resloved

Comment: I would recommend clarifying this question greatly - what kind of data are you getting and what do you expect to get out? As it stands there are quite a few uninitialized variables and your goal isn't completely clear, but this question is completely salvageable. You might find this useful: [mcve].

Comment: If `tags` were `["TAG_ONE", "TAG_TWO", "TAG_ONE"]` and `vals` were `[[18, 24, 36]` would the expected output be: `{'TAG_ONE': [18, 36], 'TAG_TWO': [24]}`?

Comment: @RonaldAaronson yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a dict comprehension:

```
{sent_tag: [vals[ind] for ind, tag in enumerate(tags) if tags[ind] == sent_tag] for sent_tag in sent_tags}
```

Think of the code like this if the comprehension structure is confusing for you:

```
output = {}
for sent_tag in sent_tags:
    val_list = []

    for ind, tag in enumerate(tags):
        if tags[ind] == sent_tag:
            val_list.append(vals[ind])

    output.update({sent_tag: val_list})
```

Either way:

your output will be:

```
{'TAG_ONE': [1, 2, 3], 'TAG_TWO': [5, 6]}
```

Comment: This is also an excellent option, and I appreciate the explanation of the comprehension structure.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can simplify that greatly using `collections.defaultdict(list)`

- zip tags and values together
- if tag match one of the interesting tags, add to dictionary

like this:

```
import collections

tags = ['irrel', 'TAG_ONE', 'TAG_ONE', 'TAG_TWO', 'TAG_ONE', 'TAG_TWO', 'irrel']

vals = ['not_rel', 1, 2, 5, 3, 6, 'not_rel']

sent_tags = {'TAG_ONE', 'TAG_TWO'}  # set is preferred when a lot of elements (faster "in" lookup)

tags_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for tag,val in zip(tags,vals):
    if tag in sent_tags:
        tags_dict[tag].append(val)

print(dict(tags_dict))  # convert to dict just to print
```

result:

```
{'TAG_TWO': [5, 6], 'TAG_ONE': [1, 2, 3]})
```

Comment: That is perfect, and precisely what I was looking for. Thank you for your assistance!